# Maximum Velocity of Coupled Oscillators with Different Masses

Tags: homework-and-exercises, coupled-oscillators

Question:
Two different masses $M_1$ and $M_2$ such that $M_1 > M_2$ are attached by a spring with spring constant $k$, which is stretched by some initial displacement $\Delta$ x from equilibrium. What are the maximum velocities reached by $M_1$ and $M_2$.

I don't particularly understand how to address a problem like this.

So far I got  $PE = {1\over2}k(\Delta x)^2$ and the $ KE = {1\over2}m_1v_1^2 + {1\over2}m_2v_2^2 $

$=> {1\over2}k(\Delta x)^2 = {1\over2}m_1v_1^2 + {1\over2}m_2v_2^2 $
But this doesn't reduce to getting the velocities of each mass.

Also the initial forces should be $F_1 = k \Delta x$ and $F_2 = -k \Delta x$
I thought this could be used as a different approach since F=ma and the integral of a is v.

Comment: so like $v_1 = sqrt(PE/ {1\over2 } M_1)$ ? but would that be the maximum velocity? cause the PE would be the initial displacement

Comment: As how the question stands I get that there are two different oscillators and not a system of coupled ones. Can you clarify?

Comment: two masses (M1, M2) attached by a spring

Comment: @noobduck that last comment makes a lot of difference. I edited your question acoordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding directly answering your question, you should consider two additional things: momentum is conserved, $0 = m_1 v_1 + m_2 v_2$ and kinetic energy is maximum when the potential energy is at its minimum, which is zero in this case. Using those two ideas you can solve this without calculating forces, which is probably the point of the assignment.

By the way, the equation for the potential energy has the spring constant in it, $PE = \frac{1}{2} k (\Delta x)^2$

Comment: what confuses be about this is that at equilibrium wouldn't $\Delta x$ = 0 s.t. PE = 0 thus $ {1\over2}m_1v_1^2 = - {1\over2}m_2v_2^2 $

Comment: So would $ {1 \over 2} m_1 v_{1max}^2 = {1 \over 2} k A^2 $ work?

Comment: Not quite, but on the right track. Conservation of momentum means that $m_1 v_1 = - m_2 v_2$, you can use that to solve for $v_1^2$ in terms of $v_2^2$. Substitute that into the equation for the energy, $\frac{1}{2} k A^2 = \frac{1}{2} m_1 v_1^2 + \frac{1}{2} m_2 v_2^2$. Giving away the answer: $v_1 = A \sqrt{\frac{k}{m_1 + m_2} \frac{m_2}{m_1}}$, the solution for $v_2$ is the same with the last fraction inverted.